# Filter numeric values from certain columns using bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have files that look like this

```
1;1;Happy Feet;WB;€546,353;-32.3%;;121;-;€4,515;€2,841,113;5;Australia, USA;:
2;3;The Departed;WB;€435,830;-34.8%;;85;-;€5,127;€1,149,495;2;Unknown;:
3;2;Eragon;Fox;€412,229;-41.6%;;90;-;€4,580;€1,752,715;3;UK, USA;:
....
```

These files get in by using tail to cut of the first 6 lines:

```
sudo tail -n+7 filename
```

Is it possible to only retain the numeric values from column 5, 10 and 11 and replace those columns with the integer values? I was thinking about awk and sed but I have absolutely no experience with these tools..

The goal would be to do this all in one command and write a file that looks like this:

```
1;1;Happy Feet;WB;546353;-32.3%;;121;-;4515;2841113;5;Australia, USA;:
2;3;The Departed;WB;435830;-34.8%;;85;-;5127;1149495;2;Unknown;:
3;2;Eragon;Fox;412229;-41.6%;;90;-;4580;1752715;3;UK, USA;:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F';' '{gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $5); gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $10); 
            gsub(/[^0-9]/, "", $11);} 1' OFS=';' file

1;1;Happy Feet;WB;546353;-32.3%;;121;-;4515;2841113;5;Australia, USA;:
2;3;The Departed;WB;435830;-34.8%;;85;-;5127;1149495;2;Unknown;:
3;2;Eragon;Fox;412229;-41.6%;;90;-;4580;1752715;3;UK, USA;:
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess you were first :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{gsub("[^0-9.]", "", $5);gsub("[^0-9.]", "", $10);gsub("[^0-9.]", "", $11)}1' OFS=';' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
1;1;Happy Feet;WB;546353;-32.3%;;121;-;4515;2841113;5;Australia, USA;:
2;3;The Departed;WB;435830;-34.8%;;85;-;5127;1149495;2;Unknown;:
3;2;Eragon;Fox;412229;-41.6%;;90;-;4580;1752715;3;UK, USA;:
```

---

EDIT: A somewhat idiomatic way to do the same using `awk` would be to make use of an array to keep the indexes:

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN{split("5,10,11",a,",")}{for(i in a){gsub("[^0-9]","",$a[i])}}1' OFS=';' inputfile
```

Comment: Almost similar to anubhava's answer. You could have upvoted his answer instead of answering a duplicate!

Comment: @user3414693 You could have posted this comment on the other answer instead?  Furthermore, what makes you say that this is a _duplicate_ of the answer?

Comment: What is different between the two answer? ;) Both of you have enough reputation. So I dont think you guys are reputation hungry! On the moral grounds whoever has answered late can delete his answer!

Comment: @user3414693 They both posted basically at the same time, there is no way to avoid this.